# How to block applications from running from removable drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, restrictions

Is it possible to block .exe, .com, .bat files from being executed from removable disks?  We would need to do this on Windows XP and Windows 7 computers. We would only need to do this on certain profiles and would also still need the drives to function as normal for most other  file types (.doc, .xls, etc..)

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a specific programming question, though it may have programming solutions. As given, I've voted to migrate it to our sister site, [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com) where you may get better answers.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't aware of this site.  Another good resource to bookmark!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SRP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx) Software Restriction Policies for Windows XP and [Applocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723686%28WS.10%29.aspx) for Windows 7.